# Declaration of an iterator out of a cycle and registered iterators: How useful they are?

Tags: c, loops, syntax, register-allocation

Why some people declare an cycle's iterator out of them? Like this:

```
int do_work(const int iqt) {
    register int i;

    for (i = 0; i < iqt; i++) {
    /* very busy work ;d */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is it a good practice?

And another questions: is it profitable to mark every iterator with `register` keyword?

Comment: you used to be forced to do it that way. Some people stuck with that style.

Comment: It's a suggestion/request to the compiler. These days compilers will do it anyway as part of basic optimizations (to my knowledge).

Comment: If `/* very busy work ;d */` als means "lots of work" then the register will probably be re-used in inner loops and would need to be stored/restored on function calls and so `register` would not be profitable at all. Leave it to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. *"Declaring the variable inside the loop"* feature was added in `C99`, any legacy code before that would be bound to declare the variables before the loop. For the legacy code, it was more of a requirement than a practice. However, post `C99` era, can have it either way. Some people (including me) find it useful to declare variables closest to their usage.
2. The `register` keyword is not a guarantee, it's a hint to the compiler. Compilers are free to ignore it. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.1

   > A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier `register`
   > suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
   > suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.